# Proof regarding convergence in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\lbrace X_n\rbrace _{n=1}^\infty$ be the series of independent random variables and $S_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n.$
Prove that if $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges in probability towards $0$, then $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges towards $0$ in probability. 
I was instructed to use $\frac {X_n} n= \frac {S_n} n- \frac  {n-1} n \frac {S_{n-1}} {n-1}$ to prove it, but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to use it in the definition of convergence in probability.

Comment: The point is that if $|\frac{S_n}{n}| < \epsilon$ and $|\frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1}| < \epsilon$, then $|\frac{X_n}{n}| < 2\epsilon$. And for large $n$, the first two inequalities hold with high probability.

Comment: Okay, I get the point, but how do I prove it formally? Or should I just rely on the intuition that if the probability of both $|\frac{S_n}{n}|$ and $|\frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1}|$ being smaller than $\epsilon$ is high, then probability of $|\frac{X_n}{n}|$ being smaller than $\epsilon$ is also very high?

Comment: You should definitely be able to prove it formally. The intuition should help you. If you think about it for a bit and are still stuck, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I'm thinking about using something like Squeeze theorem, but that's not just a simple convergence of functions, but convergence in probability.

Comment: You have to use the inequality $$\mathbb{P}(|X-Y| \geq 2 \epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq \epsilon) + \mathbb{P}(|Y| \geq \epsilon).$$

Comment: Use @saz's comment and note that ${S_{n-1} \over n}$ converges to zero in probability.

Comment: Well, where does that inequality come from?

Comment: @R.K. it comes from my initial comment.